# Can I develop for Android Phones and Tablets using the same plugin?

Tags: android

I'm new to mobile development and am a little confused. I've downloaded and installed the Android Eclipse plugin and the JDK.

I want to develop Android tablet apps as well as Android phone apps.

Can I do this with the same plugin? That is to say is development for both devices done through the same Eclipse IDE or do I need something else?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, development for both devices is done through the eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You will also have to install the [SDK Starter Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).
Once this is installed from Android SDK and AVD Manager you will be able to install the platforms you require (in your case SDK 11 for tablet development). See Step 4 on this [page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html).

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new android project in Eclipse you select the version of the SDK you want to develop for. All you have to do is select a version supported by the tablet you want to develop your application for.

Because of the way android works, an application is not developed either for a phone or a tablet, but simply for android. An application written for Andriod 2.2 will for instance run on the Galaxy Tab, with to changes.

Answer (score 0):

uvesten is right. If you want to start programming Android, here is what you need to see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869338/where-to-start-to-learn-android

ohh you changed the question title and its description. my answer is not at all true now.